# Java search entire tree for the smallest value

Tags: java, recursion, tree, binary-tree, min

This is not a binary search tree, and does not follow any strict rules.

The only rules are that each node is a positive integer and that each node can have either no children, one left child, or two children. (not just a right child).

I want to transverse through the entire tree using recursion and return the smallest value I find when finished.

I'd appreciate it if you didn't modify the signature of the method or use any extra methods apart from Math.min()

```
public static int minValue(MyNode n) {
    int root, left, right;
    int min = -1;
    if (n.obj != null) {
        root = (int) n.obj;
        left = minValue(n.left);
        right = minValue(n.right);
        if (left < right)
            min = left;
        else
            min = right;
        if (root < min)
            min = root;
    }
    return min;
}
```

Comment: What is the question/problem here?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I don't know what is wrong with my method, can anyone see where it goes wrong?

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Can your tree contain negative elements?

Comment: yeah but someone told me it was possible this way and so I took on the challenge and have failed, but yes it would of course be much easier to pass on the value as a parameter.

Comment: @Jakub "is a positive integer"

Comment: @SGM1 How will the static modifier help here, I don't think that would even compile.

Comment: Whoops confused with c XD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the problem is that for nonexistent children, you return -1, but later you don't count with that possibility. You need to remove -1 from the analysis:

```
public static int minValue(MyNode n) {
    int root, left, right;
    int min = -1;
    if (n != null) {
        root = (int) n.obj;
        left = minValue(n.left);
        right = minValue(n.right);
        if (left > -1){
            if(right > -1){
                min = Math.min(left, right);
                min = Math.min(root, min);
            }
            else{
                min = Math.min(left, root);
            }
        }
        else{
            min = root;
        }
    }
    return min;
}
```

Comment: @JakubZaverka How does that eliminate the -1 from the analysis?

Comment: @JakubZaverka Oh you meant from the actual return, -1 is still essential to the actual analysis of this algorithm since all nodes are positive; or at lease that what I felt 'analysis' meant.